# Using the < and >Symbols in xml

Tags: java, sql, xml

I am working on a system that requires generating reports from a database. I have been trying to query a database to display data according to date added and date due. The problem is the data is not being displayed in the report. The Query is as below in the .jrxml file:

```
   <parameter name="dopened" class="java.lang.String"/>
   <parameter name="dended" class="java.lang.String"/>
   <queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM CASES WHERE date_due < $P{dended} ORDER BY case_no]]>
  </queryString>*
```

I have correctly declared the parameters "dopened" and "deneded" in the corresponding .java file as follows:

```
    params.put("dopened", dopen.getDate().toString());
    params.put("dended", dend.getDate().toString());
```

Iam using a date picker to choose the date. Kindly help in pointing out what i might be missing. Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `<` with `&#60;` and getting rid of the CDATA section

Comment: Inside CDATA special characters behave as normal String, so no need to use any of `&gt;`, `&lt;` or any ascii code. It's fine. The problem is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of bracket ?

Comment: Note that these need to be `&gt;` and `&lt;` (Stack Overflow editing rules notwithstanding).

Comment: The < and > tags are not a problem since we are in the <!CDATA> tag. Problems is the sql statement is returning no results

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: you are using jasperreports or some similar solution.

The query shows a "where" clause with a date comparison which expects a Date object. The parameter "dended" is a String. You are converting "dended" with dend.getDate().toString() but the database surely expects another date format (think yy/mm/dd versus yyyy-mm-dd).

The Solution: change your parameters to java.util.Date or java.sql.Date and omit the conversion.